# export pyspark dataframes in a loop and combine into one df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I read several other posts about combining dataframes but my issue is a little different as I don't know the dataframe names in advance. Here's why:

I have a function that produces a data frame showing first purchases and subsequent purchases:

```
renew(df, 2).show()
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|2             |2         |20        |4        |3         |2        |
|2             |48        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|2             |24        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|2             |12        |12        |2        |0         |0        |
|2             |6         |3         |1        |0         |0        |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I can change the input to produce dataframe where First_Purchase = 12 (or 3, or 6 etc) and produce another dataframe:

```
renew(df, 12).show()
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|12            |2         |12        |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |1         |9         |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |48        |1         |0        |0         |0        |
|12            |24        |7         |0        |0         |0        |
|12            |12        |64        |4        |0         |0        |
|12            |6         |6         |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |3         |4         |0        |0         |0        |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I need to loop though various First_Purchase values and create one dataframe.  e.g.,

```
month = [2, 12] 
for x in month
renew_modified(all_renewals_cleaned_md, x)
```

The code above will loop through but overwrite the previous dataframe leaving me with only the last dataframe rather than append them.

If I could export each dataframe in the loop to a new and uniquely named dataframe I could concatenate them like this:

```
purchases_combined = [df1,df12,df3,df6]
```

But I haven't been able to come up with the code to loop through, export the dataframe to unique names dynamically, and then combine them so they would look like this:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|2             |2         |20        |4        |3         |2        |
|2             |48        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|2             |24        |2         |0        |0         |0        |
|2             |12        |12        |2        |0         |0        |
|2             |6         |3         |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |2         |12        |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |1         |9         |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |48        |1         |0        |0         |0        |
|12            |24        |7         |0        |0         |0        |
|12            |12        |64        |4        |0         |0        |
|12            |6         |6         |1        |0         |0        |
|12            |3         |4         |0        |0         |0        |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What You Are Failing to Do is creating a loop which will take `dataframe` created **so far** and `concatenate` current loop value(which is a dataframe)
All you need is to create an

1. `empty` dataframe, -->
2. run a loop of available dataframes -->
3. keep `concatenating` to the empty dataframe created in step 1.

Please see example below. (**btw**, this solution can be scaled by calling this function in parallel threads and using spark's FAIR job scheduling but that's out of scope for this question)

Trivial example below :

```
%pyspark

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

def concat_df(prev_df,this_df):
    prev_df.createOrReplaceTempView("prev_df")
    this_df.createOrReplaceTempView("this_df")
    # UNION dataframe created so far with current loop value
    return spark.sql(" SELECT * from prev_df UNION SELECT * FROM this_df ")
# schema needed for creating 'Empty' dataframe as first step
df_schema = StructType().add(StructField("name", StringType(), True)).add(StructField("id", IntegerType(), True))
# This empty df will be our Final result
prev_empty_df = spark.createDataFrame([], df_schema)

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("John",1),("Sam",2)], schema=["name","age"])

df2 =  spark.createDataFrame([("Adam",30),("Keaunu",25)], schema=["name","age"])



df3 = spark.createDataFrame([("David",100),("Xavier",250)], schema=["name","age"])

print("Before Concat df1 ->")
df1.show(20),
print("Before Concat df2 ->")
df2.show(20),
print("Before Concat df3 ->")
df3.show(20),

for dframe in [ df1, df2, df3 ]:
    prev_empty_df = concat_df(prev_empty_df,dframe)
    
print("FINAL DF")
prev_empty_df.show(20,False)
```

And **Result**

```
Before Concat df1 ->
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
|John|  1|
| Sam|  2|
+----+---+

Before Concat df2 ->
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|  Adam| 30|
|Keaunu| 25|
+------+---+

Before Concat df3 ->
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
| David|100|
|Xavier|250|
+------+---+

FINAL DF
+------+---+
|name  |id |
+------+---+
|John  |1  |
|Sam   |2  |
|Xavier|250|
|David |100|
|Keaunu|25 |
|Adam  |30 |
+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
result = []
month_list = [12, 2]
for x in month_list:
    df2 = renew(df, x)
    result.append(df2)
df3 = reduce(DataFrame.union, result)
df3.show()
```

produces the dataframe:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|First_Purchase|Renewal_Mo|second_buy|third_buy|fourth_buy|fifth_buy|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|            12|         2|        12|        1|         0|        0|
|            12|         1|         9|        1|         0|        0|
|            12|        48|         1|        0|         0|        0|
|            12|        24|         7|        0|         0|        0|
|            12|        12|        64|        4|         0|        0|
|            12|         6|         6|        1|         0|        0|
|            12|         3|         4|        0|         0|        0|
|             2|         2|        20|        4|         3|        2|
|             2|        48|         2|        0|         0|        0|
|             2|        24|         2|        0|         0|        0|
|             2|        12|        12|        2|         0|        0|
|             2|         6|         3|        1|         0|        0|
+--------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```